# Toggle/Pause a JavaScript Scroll Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have a function which scrolls down the page infinitely at a set rate and allows the user to scroll around by themselves:

```
function pageScroll() {
  window.scrollBy(0, 1);
  scrolldelay = setTimeout(pageScroll, 90);
}
```

What I need is a way of toggling this action on and off. I've tried the below code but it does not seem to be working. Maybe I do not understand the `scrollBy();` function very well(?) but, with this, I had really thought I would be able to call `pageScroll(true)` to get the scroll started and `pageScroll(false)` to stop it. Where am I going wrong?

```
function pageScroll(x) {
  if(x == true) {
    window.scrollBy(0, 1);
    scrolldelay = setTimeout(pageScroll, 90);
  } else if(x == false) {
    window.scrollBy(0, 0);
  }
}
```

Just to say, maybe there is a way of doing this with jQuery `scrollTop()` but I also want to allow the use to scroll around by themselves as well and `scrollTop()` gets very glitchy if you try to scroll *back* up the page.

Comment: One problem I see how is do you decide when to start auto scrolling again after user takes control and wants to read something?

Comment: As for stopping it you need to clear the timer using clearTimeout

Comment: Here's a simple jsfiddle showing a way to toggle page scrolling in the way you've described: https://jsfiddle.net/psjqLhv5/12/

Comment: @sbrass this is exactly it – thank you so much – if you'd like to put this fiddle in as an answer I'll be happy to accept it

Comment: Oh perfect! Glad I could help :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just moving my comment into a more detailed answer.

So what you're doing looks mostly correct. Basically it looks like what you want is some sort of variable tracking whether or not the page should be scrolling, and also to be toggling the scroll on some event. Here's a simple example of how that might look:

```
var shouldScroll = true;

function scroll() {
  if (!shouldScroll) {
    return;
  }
  window.scrollBy(0, 1);
  setTimeout(scroll, 90);
}

scroll();

document.getElementById('buttonId').addEventListener('click', function() {
  shouldScroll = !shouldScroll;
  scroll();
});
```

That assumes you have a button with the id `buttonId`, but other than that it really just flips the variable and ensures the page is scrolling each time it's clicked.